# How to build flutter release for distribution

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to build my flutter app for distribution to Firebase or Testflight for example. If I type

> flutter run ios --release

I get the following options:

```
Multiple valid **development certificates** available (your choice will be saved):
  1) iPhone Developer: xxxx@xxxxxx (G3xxxxx9X)
  2) iPhone Developer: xxxx xxxx (4UxxxxC8)
  a) Abort
```

How can you be able to select distribution certificate's when building with command line? If I check in Xcode my distribution profile is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first thing that you need is to create an `iOS distribution` certificate.

That one won't have the `iPhone Developer: xxxx@xxxx.com`, but will rather have the `<your release certificate signature> (GY523****)`.

You can issue it via https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list

Make sure you have a push notification services as well.

[image: distribuition 1]

And after you do it, you'll have a list of certificates like this:

[image: distribution 2]

Make sure to download and install the iOS distribution certificate on your machine.

After that, follow the article here -> https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

What you actually need to do is to change the `Runner.xcworkspace` file to accept the automatic signing using the release certificate.

That change will then reflect to the command line tool as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do u make the distrbution certificate signed, please?

Comment: @azheen, you need to enroll into iOS developer program. It costs 99$ per year. Once you are enrolled, it becomes a valid signature.

Comment: i have enrolled and created the distribution certificate and downloaded it and everything, how do i sign it after?

Comment: please, if u know tell me im very confused with apple

Comment: What do you mean? There is a tutorial I followed on Flutter official page -> https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: can we talk in a private chat, here or somewhere please, i have questions, thankyou for answering me so far